# GPU not listed in lspci after SysRQ reboot

Tags: ubuntu, ati, pci, gpu, amd

I have my Ubuntu Server machine with XFX 7970 GPU in it, and sometimes, when ATI driver fails, I have to reboot it manually.

When I'm trying to reboot the machine using SysRQ, the system reboots well, but GPU is not listed in lspci output. It appears again after hand reboot.

Is there a way to reboot it without hand reboot remotely?

Comment: Doesn't simply `reboot` work?

Comment: Nope. I have the mining program (cgminer) wich uses GPU, abd when GPU driver fails, cgminer cannot be killed, and, therefore, reboot cannot be completed

Comment: `reboot` after you've forced the boot with SysRq?

Comment: You mean call `reboot` and then SysRQ reboot?

Comment: No. Reboot with SysReq, and if that doesn't "recover" the graphics card, plain `reboot`.

Comment: I've tried this, but without luck. And there is some strange thing - my GPU has 100% fans even after several reboots, it looks like some program still uses it

Comment: Most likely the unpowering of the GPU is required to clear whatever state it's in. I'd look to see if there is a way to achieve that from the command line (esentially power-cycling  the GPU).